# Limit MJPEG stream bandwidth

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-capture, mencoder, video-streaming

I have a very simple webcam, but it supports MJPEG streaming.

Webcam is in remote location, and that location internet connection has a very low upload speed.

I can capture that MJPEG stream with ffmpeg/mencoder, but this kills the location connection.
Now, I've set up cam to upload a screenshot via ftp every 2 seconds, to my server and server converts it back into videos, this works for now without killing the internet con.

Is there a way that I can limit the MJPEG stream bandwidth (from the recording server site) ?